# ImageNet Weights for Character Recognition?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I contructed a network which uses the bottom of EffcicientNet-B0 model (link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11946) which is pretrained on ImageNet. These weights are freezed during the whole training process.

```
efnB0_model = efn.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
efnB0_model.trainable = False
```

After that, I am using a customized top to recognize characters on license plates.
Now, I read an article on https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reviewing-efficientnet-increasing-the-accuracy-and-robustness-of-cnns-6aaf411fc81d, where the author writes:

*"Pre-trained models are models that were previously trained and saved on a large dataset such as ImageNet. Thus, the features learned are useful for many new computer vision problems. However, these new problems may include classes that are completely different from the original task, and should not be ignored.
For example, an image can train a network on ImageNet (where classes are mostly animals and everyday objects) and then reuse this trained network for problems as disparate as identifying car models. However, in this case, you’d need different approaches specific to your problem in order to classify data that doesn’t exist in the ImageNet dataset."* (Ayyüce Kızrak, 2017)

What I am wondering is: Is my attempt to recognize characters on license plates and using weights trained on ImageNet suitable or should I use another approach? I am a little bit confused now...

Comment: It is suitable - rest can be judged from the accuracy - output results the model gets.

Not sure if you have done the following - 
1. Customize the model output - number of classes - if the range of different characters on a license plate be from 0 to 9 then  "n = 10".
2. Further loss can be soft max if not done already.
Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: I already did this. I have number plates with 7 characters and 35 possible characters, so the shape of the target variable is `(7, 35)`, correct? And I also applied the softmax as activation function on the last layer.

Comment: 7 & 35 - what is the difference?

Comment: 7 is the length of a license plate and 35 are the possible characters for each of this seven positions on a license plate.

Comment: So , 35 will be the target like n = 35 .
And by 7 being the length - I understand that the input image size for all license plates have a dimension of say 7*7.
So the input image size will be 7 here.

In the above model instantiation - input_shape=(224, 224, 3) would be amended .

Comment: No, the input image size is 224, 224, 3. But on all license plates we have 7 characters and for each of this characters we have 35 possibilities (10 numbers and 35 letters). Therefore, the shape (7, 35)

Comment: Keep output classes = 35 

Output would look like below - 

Char 0 = 0.0111
Char 1 = 0.889
Char 2 = 0.0711
Char 3= 0.70
.
.... Char 34 = 0.23

Across each character - there is a probability of confidence which denotes how confident the model is about the presence of a given number in the license plate.
Sort them using argmax from high to low.
Last, pick top 7 i.e. class 0 to 6.

Comment: I do not get this part... Because actually I do need the output for all characters at once?

Comment: Yes, the above would do the same.